# nginx match specific word in location

Tags: regex, nginx

I am having trouble matching a specific word in nginx $request_body variable. 
I want to proxy pass if the body request has a special word in it,

So my approach is this:

```
 location ~ \.php$ {
if ($request_body ~* (.*)) {                                        
        proxy_pass http://test.proxy;
            break;
    }

# other case...
}
```

This matches everything and the if statement works, 
but if I change the regexp in any way, I can't get a hit.

So my question now is:

**How do i need to define the regexp in nginx correctly to match against, "target" for example?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't hold your breath. You can toggle http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_body_in_single_buffer if it counts. But I don't think you can match request body

Comment: I do now understand that the problem is not within the regexp, but that $request_body seems to be empty at this point, I even tried the echo module which provides a read_request_body method, but still empty :(

Comment: Exactly. The http://wiki.nginx.org/EmbeddedPerlModule doc hints that $request_body is available when nginx is holding the body in memory as oppose to in a temp file. "It is necessary to limit its [body] size with the aid of client_max_body_size and to assign sufficient size for the buffer using client_body_buffer_size." I guess it's suggested to set client_max_body_size to a lower than client_body_buffer_size value.

Comment: yeah but even when changing those two settings, the variable remains empty. I don't get it, is there no way to specify the behaviour based no the request body?

Comment: Well, to be fair, the settings described relate to $request_body for the perl module. So, if you'd use it (with has_request_body call), it should be there. The thing is, the handler can be called before the body received from the client. Thus the perl module has a method to specify a function to be called when the body finally received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems.

1. "($request_body ~* (.*))" never matches anything as stated by someone else and so the the "other case" is always the outcome
2. More importantly, it uses "proxy_pass" with "if" which is classically evil. http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil.

To get what you want, use the 3rd party ngx_lua module (v0.3.1rc24 and above) ...

```
location ~ \.php$ { 
    rewrite_by_lua ' 
        ngx.req.read_body() 
        local match = ngx.re.match(ngx.var.request_body, "target") 
        if match then 
            ngx.exec("@proxy");
        else 
            ngx.exec("@other_case");     
        end 
    '; 
} 

location @proxy {    
    # test.proxy stuff 
    ... 
}

location @other_case {
    # other_case stuff 
    ... 
}
```

You can get ngx_lua at https://github.com/chaoslawful/lua-nginx-module/tags.

PS. Bear in mind that rewrite by lua is always executed after the nginx rewrite directives so if you put any such directives in the other case, they will be executed first and you will get funnies.

You should put all your rewrites within the rewrite by lua context for consistent results. This is the reason for the "if ..else..end" arrangement for the "other case".

---

You may need this longer version

---

```
location ~ \.php$ { 
    rewrite_by_lua '
        --request body only available for POST requests
        if ngx.var.request_method == "POST"
            -- Try to read in request body
            ngx.req.read_body()
            -- Try to load request body data to a variable
            local req_body = ngx.req.get_body_data()
            if not req_body then 
                -- If empty, try to get buffered file name
                local req_body_file_name = ngx.req.get_body_file()
                --[[If the file had been buffered, open it, 
                read contents to our variable and close]] 
                if req_body_file_name then
                    file = io.open(req_body_file_name)
                    req_body = file:read("*a")
                    file:close()
                end
            end
            -- If we got request body data, test for our text
            if req_body then
                local match = ngx.re.match(req_body, "target") 
                if match then 
                    -- If we got a match, redirect to @proxy
                    ngx.exec("@proxy")
                else
                     -- If no match, redirect to @other_case
                    ngx.exec("@other_case")
                end
            end
        else
            -- Pass non "POST" requests to @other_case
            ngx.exec("@other_case")
        end
    ';
}
```

Comment: I will try that thanks, though I would rather not use lua for this :(

Comment: Why not if I may ask? "IF" in Nginx is not a classic programing conditional statement and is just a rewrite attribute. If Igor had known how much confusion it'll cause, he'll have named it differently when putting it in. In your case, you need the classic scripting conditional statement and you have to use a scripting language to achieve this. There is no way around it. You basically have two options: The embedded Perl Module or the Lua Module. Choose your poison :)

Comment: you're probably right, I would love to get this behaviour without any third party modules ;) but I just read up on if and it realls is evil :D thanks for the help... I will take a look at perl for now xD

Comment: I doubt if the lua module will be third party for very much longer. It is virtually indispensable to running Nginx beyond the most basic setup.

Comment: is there a reason why you chose lua over the embedded perl? or are you just more familiar with it? hadn't had the change to try it yet

Answer (score 0):

[Manual:](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule)

> Note: for curly braces( { and } ), as they are used both in regexes
>   and for block control, to avoid conflicts, regexes with curly braces
>   are to be enclosed with double quotes (or single quotes).

so try

```
if ($request_body ~* "(.*)")
```

**Other comments:** The code `.*` matches everything. I would instead use `\w`, since Perl regex seems to be available.

Your current if -clause is always wrong so no hit is the right output for it.