# nginx conditional proxy pass based on request body content

Tags: nginx, proxy

I am trying to configure nginx to proxy pass the request to another server, only if the $request_body variable matches on a specific regular expression.But it is not working for me.

```
 server{
        listen 80 default;
        server_name www.applozic.com;

        location / {
                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

                if ($request_body ~* (.*)appId(.*)) {
                   proxy_pass http://apps.applozic.com;
                }
        }
```

}

request body is::

```
              {
               "applicationId": "appId",
               "authenticationTypeId": 1,
               "enableEncryption": false,
               "notificationMode": 0,
               "deviceType": 4,
              }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx match specific word in location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888165/nginx-match-specific-word-in-location)

Comment: Is there any solution for TCP requests? Actually i want to route TCP requests based on body content.

Answer (score 12):

I found the solution.

I did following changes in nginx(open resty) config file

```
upstream algoapp {
   server 127.0.0.0.1:543;
}
upstream main {
   server 127.0.0.1:443;
}

location /rest/ws/login {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
   proxy_redirect off;
   if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
   proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:543;
   }
   if ($request_method = POST ) {
   set $upstream '';
   access_by_lua '
   ngx.req.read_body()
   local data = ngx.req.get_body_data()
   local  match = ngx.re.match(ngx.var.request_body, "appId")
   if match then
      ngx.var.upstream = "algoapp"
   else
   ngx.var.upstream = "main"
   end
   ';
   proxy_pass https://$upstream;
   }
}
```

Comment: I trying to implement the same, I am not able to retrive the value of the upstream variable, but i am using the config in location, does this work for rewrite also?

Answer (score 2):

As best I can tell the issue is that the variable `$request_body` may not have been read into memory at the time your if statement is executing.

Suggested alternatives would be to use the lua support or [compile nginx with the echo modules and run echo_request_body](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/05/23/configuring-nginx-to-log-post-data-on-linux-rhel/).

Answer (score 1):

A working example with automated tests in case useful for someone else: https://github.com/ericminio/learning-nginx/tree/master/payload_filter

The config

```
map $request_body $matching {
    default       'not_matching';
    include       /etc/nginx/conf.d/matching;
}

server {                                                                              
    default_type  text/plain;

    location /ping {
        return 200 'pong';
    }

    location / {  
        proxy_set_header 'X-Matching' $matching;
        proxy_pass http://localhost/routing;           
    } 

    location /routing {
        try_files /unknown-file-to-trigger-redirect @_$http_x_matching;
    }
    location @_matching {
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:5015;
    }
    location @_not_matching {
        proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:5066;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not so easy when come to using integration , like some circumstances your nginx does not really allow you to do extra proxy stuff to change the whole design, then you can try [nginx-if-request-body](https://github.com/Taymindis/nginx-if-request-body) to achieve the result

```
http {
 ....
     
 map "$uri" $forward_status {
    default 100; # 100 means nothing return, continue to proxy phase
    "~*.+?\.(css|js|bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|pict|png|svg|swf|tif)$" 418;
 }
 map "$request_body" $forward_status_by_body {
    default 100;
    "abc123xxx" 418;
    "~*.+?\.(css|js|bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|pict|png|svg|swf|tif)$" 418;
  }

server {
 ...
    error_page 418 =200 @welcome_if_request_body;

    location @welcome_if_request_body {
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        return 200 "welcome_if_request_body, you hit it";
    }

    location = / {
        if_request_body on;
        return_status_if_body_eq "ASD" 418 on;
        return_status_if_body_eq "foo" 418;
        return_status_if_body_eq "john" 418;
        return_status_if_body_startswith "report" 418;
        return_status_if_body_contains "report" 418;
        return_status_if_body_regex "^[\d]+?abc" 418;
        return_status_if_variable_map_to $forward_status;
        return_status_if_variable_map_to $forward_status_by_body;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7777;

    }
...
  }
}
```