# how to rewrite response based on request body content in nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, openresty

I have requirement where i need to have a rewrite the response with static context in nginx based on content from the request body say "fruit":"apple",

The nginx location with rewrite config as mentioned below, 
o

tried referring to nginx conditional proxy pass based on request body content solution, but getting 401 response.

```
location ~* /getItems/fruits
{
    if ($request_body ~ (.*)apple(.*))
    {
        rewrite ^ /apple.json break;
    }

    if ($request_body ~* (.*)orange(.*))
    {
        rewrite ^ /orange.json break;
    }

    rewrite ^ 401 break;
}
```

**Expected**
on sending the "fruit":"apple" we should get the apple.json
on sending the "fruit":"orange" we should get the orange.json

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245660/nginx-conditional-proxy-pass-based-on-request-body-content people say that such thing requires using lua scripting.